# Analog of MATLAB's cwtft2 in PyWavelet?

Tags: python, matlab, wavelet, wavelet-transform

I am trying to implement 2D Continuous Wavelet Transform in Python but looks like the PyWavelet library only has a 1D CWT implementation. Does it have a 2D implementation of CWT similar to MATLAB's `cwtft2` function? Is there any other library in Python that does this? Thanks!